# Regular expression - validate special characters between substrings

Tags: regex

I want to validate the special characters in a string. example "A;B,C;D,E;F,G;H" it means that "A;B" is a pair and "C;D" is next pair etc.. pairs are separated by "," So I need to validate this string should be same as above and should not start/end with "," and last pair should be "X;Y" and maximum 4 pairs. Can any one help me?

Comment: The last pair in your example is not `X;Y`

Comment: sorry. I said for example format. It should be G;H

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to match

```
^([A-Z];[A-Z],){0,3}X;Z$
```

Comment: I tried "([0-9A-Za-z]{1};[0-9A-Za-z]{1},){0,2}([0-9A-Za-z]{1};[0-9A-Za-z]{1})$" But "AA;B,AAA;C" returns true. It should be false. String should be in "A;B,A;C" format. I mean "OneCharacter;OneCharacter". Where did I wrong?

Comment: @Ramesh No, `AA;B,AAA;C` should return `false` for that regex. What language are you using? (although it shouldn't really matter)

Comment: @Ramesh I believe your regex is matching the last 'A;C' in the sample 'AA;B,AAA;C' string.  Since the regex you supplied isn't anchored at the beginning with a '^' (beginning of string) and the first group of the regex can match between 0 and 2 times '{0,2}'.  The first group is not matching at all and the second group is matching the last A;C and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `^([A-z];[A-z],){0,3}X;Y$` .

This assumes an anchored string consisting of pairs made up of single alphabetic characters separated by a `;`, with pairs separated by a `,`.  The last pair must always be `X;Y` and there can be between 0 and 3 pairs before that.

Comment: I tried "([0-9A-Za-z]{1};[0-9A-Za-z]{1},){0,2}([0-9A-Za-z]{1};[0-9A-Za-z]{1})$" But "AA;B,AAA;C" returns true. It should be false. String should be in "A;B,A;C" format. I mean "OneCharacter;OneCharacter". Where did I wrong?